# When will Literature get its own badges?

Tags: support, badges

This is my first time to participate in an SE beta. I've gotten a badge or two already, but I noticed that they show up in my notifications as the same shape as whatever other SE sites use (i.e., a film reel from Movies & TV).

When will Literature get its own badge shapes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a problem for 2019

Comment: I'm voting to leave open because this is a genuine question with a clear answer. The fact that the OP didn't know the answer doesn't mean the question should be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open, because even though it may be chronologically misplaced, it's still a valid question for Meta.Lit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will when it gets its own site design. However, that will be in a *really looong* time, probably years.

Currently the site is in private beta stage, where things like the initial scope and policies are hashed out and a good base stock in questions and answers is gathered.

When it goes well (what it currently does) it will enter public beta stage in *about* 3 weeks. And then it might be in public beta for a very long time, [until the traffic is high enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/162011) for the site to graduate. This might take years, though, *if* it ever happens. And when that happens, it will eventually get its site design at some point (though, not necessarily directly when graduating), probably including custom badge icons (little book thingies anyone?).

But at this time it's really a little early to worry about this.

Comment: IIRC it's only 1 week from private to public beta?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk I don't think so. The last times I saw were *at least* 2 weeks, but probably 3. Don't get distracted by the 7 days talk that's all around official documentations, that's as deprecated as the 90 days public betas.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if it's in the official documentation, it's wrong.

Comment: "*when [graduation] happens, it will get its site design at some point*" - [anime.se] and [law.se] would like a word with you ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Why? They will still get their design at *some* point, too. Notice how I didn't say at the *same* point as the graduation. I tried to elaborate a little more, though.

Comment: Well, some of those sites have waited so long (with SE design staff reshuffles in the meanwhile) that who knows whether they'll *ever* get designs ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor Sure, but *officially* they *will*. That is the prevailing premise until SE ultimately says "cancelled!"...or restructures the entire process into something completely different.

Comment: @b_jonas If ever, then certainly not yet. It seems way too uncertain for any hasty answer updates yet.

Answer (score 3):

Never.

The previous answer was correct about the procedure followed before: SE sites get custom design some time after the graduation, but this takes ages because the designers are busy.  But [a new announcement two weeks ago by SE product manager Joe Friend explain changes in this procedure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/222298).  Sites will still get custom design, but they will no longer get custom badge icons.